# Show current date and time on Sony α6000

Tags: camera-settings, sony, date, time

Is there any way to display the current date and time on a Sony α6000, apart from going into the menu and trying to set it?

I find this feature very useful and it was very easy on my Canon DSLR, but I can't find this option in my Sony α6000.

Comment: Do you mean basically just to use it as a clock?

Comment: @mattdm yes, exactly

Comment: Using a camera as a clock is a non-photographic use of photographic equipment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a camera as a clock.

Comment: vtc b/c This question is not about photography.

Comment: There is a photographic argument for this I think... There might be some requirement to take a photo at a particular moment (could be any reason - astronomical, sentimental, security-related, etc), and it could be useful if the date/time was viewable on the rear LCD for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can check the photo review screens. At least one of them should display the date when the picture was taken. If it is not there, go into menu options and edit your photo-review screens.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done.You can view time from exif.